# How to perform autoscaling in ec2 inside a vpc?

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I want to perform autoscaling without using CLI tools. I want to do it from the console itself.

The instance is in vpc ? how can i apply the autoscale policy on instance

Any lead is appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43307/discussion-between-user3086014-and-slayedbylucifer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation:
Follow the instructions on [how to Set Up an Auto-Scaled and Load-Balanced Application](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-register-lbs-with-asg.html)

Notes:
The instance, created outside of AutoScaling Group can be added to Elastic Load Balancer, but will not be monitored or managed by AutoScaling group.

Instance, created outside of AutoScaling Group can be marked as unhealthy by Elastic Load Balancer if the health check fails, but it will not cause AutoScaling Group to spawn a new instance.